# Venezuelan crisis of 1902–03: Why is there a Russian flag on the cover of the prominent newspaper 'Le Petit Parisien'?

Tags: economy, russia, finance, caribbean, venezuela

The Venezuelan crisis of 1902–03[a] was a naval blockade from December 1902 to February 1903 imposed against Venezuela by Britain, Germany and Italy over President Cipriano Castro's refusal to pay foreign debts and damages suffered by European citizens in the Venezuelan civil war.

The most famous depiction of the crisis were featured in the newspaper 'Le Petit Parisien'. My eyes caught the sight of the Russian flag. I couldn't find any information about this strange detail. Could someone please shed light on this? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think this is a color error (in reproduction, printing, fading, etc.) It is a 19th Century Venezuelan flag with the cluster of stars visible on the blue bar.

[image]

Comment: There does in fact appear to be some kind of feature in the center of that flag that looks very much like this circle of stars.

Comment: I read somewhere that yellow was difficult to reproduce in 1900s pulp media.....no time to seek source though.

Answer (score 7):

After zooming in, it does look like the white part is a faded yellow and there is a circle of stars in the middle of the flag (as pointed out in [Aaron's answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/37592/16355)):

[image]